# Will another Logitech K350 keyboard work with the same receiver?

Tags: wireless-keyboard

My [Logitech K350](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-keyboard-k350) wireless keyboard has a broken spacebar.  I can get another used Logitech K350 keyboard, but without the USB receiver.  Will it work with the old receiver from the broken keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

It should.  The fob is what Logitech calls a ["Unifying" receiver](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/promotions/6072), which is not device-specific.  It is supposed to work with any (or multiple) devices that are compatible (appears to be limited to Logitech products), which would include another of the same model keyboard.

Comment: it worked for a new M510 (mouse)